# JPanel on top of another JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlayer

I have been using JPanels for a while and now want to place a JPanel on top of another JPanel.

I have looked at using JLayer but I was wondering If there is a solution to just set the layer of the bottom and top, I don't want to set each components layer if possible.

**Example**

```
JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();      # Set as bottom panel
JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();         # Set as top panel
JPanel sidePanel = new JPanel();        # Don't have to set
JPanel anotherSidePanel = new JPanel(); # Don't have to set
```

If this isn't possible what is the best solution for this, Thanks.

Comment: Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have the main panel use a `BorderLayout`.

Then you can do something like:

```
mainPanel.add(leftSide, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
mainPanel.add(rightSide, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
JLayeredPane lp = new JLayeredPane();
mainPanel.add(lp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: Wow, never knew there was such thing as a `JLayeredPane`, Thanks it worked!

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like what you want is a layout manager. There are a few different ones that suit different needs. There's a link at the bottom of this post.

My personal favorite is GridLayout. So for what you want to do, you can do this:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
//the first number is the number of rows, the second is the number of columns

JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
panel.add(topPanel);
panel.add(bottomPanel);
```

That will do what you want.

If you wanted to read more about them, here's a link:
[Oracle Docs on Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Answer (score 3):

I know this is quite late, but if anyone now has this issue, I suggest using a `BoxLayout`. `BorderLayout` can only have one cell in each of its five locations, and `GridLayout`'s cells are all the same dimension. If you want to stack different sized JPanels, here's how `BoxLayout` can be implemented:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Intro to BoxLayout");
JPanel container = new JPanel();

JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
panel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(X1, Y1));
JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
panel2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(X2, Y2));

container.setLayout(new BoxLayout(container, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
container.add(panel1);
container.add(panel2);

frame.add(container);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

where X1, Y1, X2, Y2 are arbitrary panel dimensions.